# Send Table contents from CSV file in Outlook Mail Body using Python

Tags: python, outlook, smtp

i programmed a code to send a outlook mail , which should contain the contents of CSV file as it's body , Mail part is working fine . But the table appears to be distorted .

[![MailBody][1]][1]

So here is there anyway to arrange this . and make it pretty .

and here is my code :

```
def sendMailt():

    print("*** SENDING MAIL ****")
    email_user = 'ABC@domain.com'
    email_send = 'DCF@domain.com'

    subject = ''

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = 'Hi Team , Please Open This attachment for Folderstat Report,'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    text = """
    Hello, Friend.

    Here is your data:

    {table}

    Regards,

    Me"""

    with open(filtered_CSV) as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        data = list(reader)

    text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=['Unnamed: 0','id','path','name','extension','size','FolderSize in GB','LastAccessTime','LastModifiedTime','LastCreationTime','folder','Total Number of files','Absolute File Count','depth','parent','uid','Oldest File Timestamp','Recent File Timestamp','Folder Modified Timestamp','Status','md5]'] ,tablefmt='orgtbl'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('domain')

    sender = 'ABC@domain.com'
    reciever = ['DCF@domain.com']
    server.sendmail(sender, reciever, text)
    server.quit()
    print("Mail SEND")
```

and also when i receive mail , am not able to see subject or receivers ID
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Gxy.png

Answer (score 0):

if you Use html in tablefmt you can get the data in decent format

```
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

text = """
Hello, Friend.

Here is your data:

{table}

Regards,

Me"""

with open(filtered_CSV) as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)

html = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html")
# for html design ( you can add whatever style you want)
html = html.replace('<table>', """<table border=1 style="
                        border-color:grey;
                        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
                        font-size: 15px;
                        padding: 5px;">""")
server = smtplib.SMTP('domain')
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(html, 'html')])
msg['From'] = from address
msg['To'] = to address
msg['Subject'] = "your subject"

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
print("Mail SEND")
```